# How to design the release of Gradel In Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW93h.png)

in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the build.gradle (app) file and find

```
android {

... [some other stuff]

}
```

then at the top in the android{} section add

```
compileSdkVersion 30
```

It should look like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "...."
    
    defaultConfig{
        [...]
    }


}
```